# How to maintain an almost identical repository?

Tags: git

I need to maintain some repositories that are almost identical to another repository, with just a few changes. So for example I would like to be able to pull from the original repository, but keep the changes I have made, and then push to my own version of it. Is that possible?

Comment: It sounds like you want to use git exactly as intended.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I see how one could think that after reading my  question, but I don't think this is the most common use case for git if you read carefully. Think of a fork, but you want to keep up with the developments in the original repository. Normally when you fork, it's because the original died, got compromised, or you just want to create a pull request. No? So you don't keep up with its developments, you leave it behind.

Comment: Forking in its basics means that you just create your own copy of the project. It does not necessarily mean anything about the state of the original repository or how much you plan to keep the fork updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly the scenario Git does when you simply clone a remote repository. When you clone a repository, you get a local repository which contains all commits from the remote repository but works independent from it. You can pull in new changes from the remote to update it, but you can also work in the repository without affecting the remote and later decide to push some commits if you want to.

Now of course, a local repository might not be what you were trying to get, so instead, you can just create another remote repository which you push to to “back up” your local repository. This is pretty much how contributing on GitHub works: You have one original repository (often called “*upstream* repository”), and you fork that into your own GitHub account. Then you clone your fork locally, so you have a working directory and can contribute. When you push, you first push to your fork (your “*origin* repository” since you cloned from it), keeping it up to date with your local repository. But at any point, you can also decide to push something to the upstream repository, the original repository.

Keep in mind that you are able to keep any number of remote repositories in your local repository. It’s up to you to decide when to push something to which repository.